# Strange image produced by matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I have a png image as follows:
[image]

I wrote the following script to read into matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

fi = "map.png"
data = np.array(Image.open(fi))
print data.shape

plt.imshow(data)
plt.show()
```

But the image looks different.

[image]
How to make it look similiar to the first one?
I mean, the colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib handles images much more transparently if you use the [mpimg package](https://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html):

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

fi = "map.png"
data = mpimg.imread(fi)
print(data.shape)
plt.imshow(data)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The image you have provided is not a Grayscale image

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
    import matplotlib.image as image_rgb
    image = image_rgb.imread("image.png")
    plot.imshow(image)
    plot.show()
```

I have not used the PIL library and it produces apt results.